# Absolute import is not working with fastify-autoload

Tags: node.js, typescript, absolute-path, fastify

I'm building fastify application with typescript and I'm having problems with using absolute import.

```
{
  "extends": "fastify-tsconfig",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src"]
}
```

This is my tsconfig.json file.

```
import { User } from "entity/User";
import { FastifyPluginAsync } from "fastify";

const example: FastifyPluginAsync = async (fastify, opts): Promise<void> => {
  fastify.get("/", async function (request, reply) {
    const users = await fastify.db.manager.find(User);
    return users;
  });
};

export default example;
```

And this is the part where I used abslute import.

Visual studio code doesn't display error with this but when I run the app, there occurs `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` error.

I guess this is because of the fastify-autoload plugin.
Of course, I could use import with relative path instead but it would make code messy and hard to read, so I hope I can get around this.

If anyone have experience with this, please help me.

Comment: Could you share with us the script where you are running the autoload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an alternative solution of using tsc-alias.
Here's my tsconfig.json file.

```
{
  "extends": "fastify-tsconfig",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "paths": {
      "@entity/*": ["entity/*"],
      "@controllers/*": ["controllers/*"]
    }
  },
  "tsc-alias": {
    "verbose": false,
    "resolveFullPaths": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src"]
}
```